# How to stop resizing after refresh of new Date()

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm currently working on React clock app. Everything is working just fine except for resizing my 



 element. This resizing occurs whenever current time is updated but only on few numbers. I think somewhere between 01 and 20 ,but it doesn't matter.

I think the problem is that every number is taking different amount of space ,so for example '1' has smaller width than '5' ,so there comes the resize.

I've tried to add **letter-spacing** attribute in css but it doesn't work.

Does anybody know how to prevent this?

```
function App() {
  const [time,setTime] = useState({
  currentTime : ''
  })

 //Insert current time to state
 function currentTime(){
   let timeNow = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('it-IT');
   setTime(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    currentTime:timeNow
   }))
 }

 //Update current time every second
 useEffect(()=>{
   setInterval(() => {
   currentTime()
   }, 1000);
 },[])

return (
  <div className="App">
    <p>{time.currentTime}</p>
  </div>
);
}
```

Comment: use monospace font :)

Comment: Thanks! When I was downloading digital clock font I was wondering what monospace version of this font means :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using monospace font was the answer for this problem